# Shall amounts in Tuition Statement be reported in Federal tax report?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I received [1098-T form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1098t.pdf) from my graduate school in US. In the form, there are two nonzero amounts:

- Amounts billed for qualified tuition
  and related expenses (box 2)
- scholarships or grants (box 5)

I was wondering

1. if the two amounts should be
   reported somewhere in [federal tax
   1040 form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf)?
2. Payments received for qualified tuition and related expenses (box1) is zero, but on the back of the same paper, Personal Payments are nonzero which is what I actually paid for my tuition. Are the two not consistent with each other? Shall I report the nonzero Personal Payments that I paid somewhere in 1040 form?
3. The instruction of 1040 says there
   are two ways to claim the benefits

   1. reported as adjustment to income in
      line 34 "tuition and fees" of Form
      1040 attached with Form 8917
   2. reported as tax credit in line 49 "educational expenses" of Form 1040 attached with Form 8863

   If I understand correctly, it also
   says that I can choose only one of
   the above two ways, not both, does
   it? If yes, I was also which way to
   go? Does the choice depends on
   whichever favors me?
4. when trying the second way in part 3
   using Form 8863, I have to choices,
   either "the American opportunity
   credit" or "the lifetime learning
   credit", but not both. The former
   requires that student must be
   pursuing an undergraduate degree or
   other recognized education
   credential, while the latter
   requires that student does not need
   to be pursuing a degree or other
   recognized education credential. I
   am a  graduate student, not an
   undergraduate, and am I qualified
   for the former, i.e., "the American
   opportunity credit"?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the information on your 1098-T is required to be reported on your federal tax return as it is considered taxable income. You may receive offsets and benefits in the form of credits to make up for the potential tax liability.

Your choice of how it is reported is determined by what education based credits you qualify for and which benefit you the most.

I would recommend using a tax preparation program (like TurboTax) to guide you through the process. That way you can quickly see which of the various filing options are most favorable for you.